# How to create queue system to send emails in zend framework 2.2.?

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, zend-queue

I want to prepare a queue for my system to send emails using queue. 
Suppose i have one script to insert some record and send an email then i will add these email in queue  and when queue execute then email would be sent.

Can you suggest me some examples that instruct me how to do with zend-framework2 ?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried ?

Stack overflow does not work like this, you can't just ask for a work, and expect people will provide nicely.

Regarding your demands now I'd recommend, using [SlmQueue](https://github.com/JouwWeb/SlmQueue) for Zend framework.

If you use doctrine I'll advise this [plugin](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmQueueDoctrine)

If you want a more complexe solution I would recomment a soft implementing AMQP protocol such as [rabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)